# Concat Column Values with a separator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to concatenate column values with a separator and assign it to variable.

If column value is `null`, there's no need to add separator.

For example: `A|B|C|D`

If B is null `A|C|D`.

I tried with `CONCAT` function, but if B is null, it results in `A||C|D`

```
DECLARE @OldValue VARCHAR(8000); 

SELECT @OldValue =  CONCAT([FloorCode],'|',
                           [FloorName],'|',
                           [BuildingID],'|',
                           [HCMLocationCode],'|',
                           [IsActive]) 
FROM tblFloor_Master 
WHERE  FloorID = @FloorID;
```

`@FloorID` is an input parameter of SP

Comment: What did you try, can you please add that code?

Comment: Can you put your actual table with data and expected results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Comment: @R.Nanayakkara - Added the code in the post

Comment: @SreelalT Check for NULL and do formatting. See answer below. Suraj Kumar's answers will also give you the desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT @OldValue = CONCAT('',
    CASE WHEN [FloorCode] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT([FloorCode],'|') END,
    CASE WHEN [FloorName] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT([FloorName],'|') END,
    CASE WHEN [BuildingID] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT([BuildingID],'|') END,
    CASE WHEN [HCMLocationCode] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT([HCMLocationCode],'|') END,
    [IsActive])
FROM tblFloor_Master 
WHERE  FloorID = @FloorID;
```

Comment: this is a very long solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
create table tempTable (id int identity(1, 1),col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1), col4 char(1))
insert into tempTable values ('A', NULL, 'C', 'D')

select * into #NewTable from(
select id, col1 as Value from tempTable where col1 is not null
union
select id, col2 as Value from tempTable where col2 is not null
union
select id, col3 as Value from tempTable where col3 is not null
union
select id, col4 as Value from tempTable where col4 is not null
)a

SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT '| ' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM #NewTable 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,' ') List_Output
FROM #NewTable t
GROUP BY ID
```

The output is as shown below

```
ID  List_Output
---------------
1     A| C| D
```

If you do not want to put space between values then you can try this

```
SELECT  ID
       ,STUFF((SELECT '|' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM #NewTable 
         WHERE ID = t.ID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') List_Output
FROM #NewTable t
GROUP BY ID
```

In this case the output will be

```
ID  List_Output
---------------
1   A|C|D
```

You can also try the below actual query using stored procedure

```
create table tblFloor_Master (FloorID int identity(1, 1),
                              FloorCode char(1), 
                              FloorName char(1),
                              BuildingID char(1),
                              HCMLocationCode char(1))

insert into tblFloor_Master values ('A', NULL, 'C', 'D')

GO
--To create a procedure
create proc uspGetConcateValue
@FloorId int
as
BEGIN
    select * into #tblFloor_Master from(
    select FloorId, FloorCode as Value from tblFloor_Master where FloorCode is not null
    union
    select FloorId, FloorName as Value from tblFloor_Master where FloorName is not null
    union
    select FloorId, BuildingID as Value from tblFloor_Master where BuildingID is not null
    union
    select FloorId, HCMLocationCode as Value from tblFloor_Master where HCMLocationCode is not null
    )a

    SELECT  FloorId
           ,STUFF((SELECT '|' + CAST(Value AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
             FROM #tblFloor_Master 
             WHERE FloorId = t.FloorId
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') List_Output
    FROM #tblFloor_Master t
    where FloorID = @FloorId
    GROUP BY FloorId
END
```

Live demo here - [**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/PHD51412)

Comment: This query will also run in lower versions of SQL server where Concat() function is not available.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
   TRIM ('|' FROM 
      regexp_replace(
          CONCAT('','|','COLB','|','','|','COLD','|','COLE')
          ,'[\|]+'
          ,'|'
          ,'g'
      )
   )

Comment: tested on postgres

Comment: Welcome to SO!  FYI, this question is asking about SQL server (see the tags and title), not Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple as doing `replace`, replace || to | then replace ||| to | since the maximum number of | is 3.

```
DECLARE @OldValue VARCHAR(8000); 

SELECT @OldValue =  replace(replace(CONCAT([FloorCode],'|',
                           [FloorName],'|',
                           [BuildingID],'|',
                           [HCMLocationCode],'|',
                           [IsActive]),'||','|'),'|||','|')
FROM tblFloor_Master 
WHERE  FloorID = @FloorID;
```

Comment: Hi, given all of the items are empty you get ```||||``` before replacing, ```||``` after the inner replace and also ```||``` as final (wrong) result, since you watching for 3 times |. This solution is also wrong for ```|||```(2 adjacent fiels empty). The replace better could be ```||``` to ```|```, two times in a row: ```||||->||->|``` and ```|||->||->|``` for reducing up to 4 ```|``` to only 1. Switching inner and outer replace could solve the issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

I've only just discovered it too, but the `CONCAT_WS` (With Separator) function is designed for this problem. It has been available since SQL Server 2017.

```sql
DECLARE @OldValue VARCHAR(8000); 

SELECT @OldValue =  CONCAT_WS('|', 
                           [FloorCode],
                           [FloorName],
                           [BuildingID],
                           [HCMLocationCode],
                           [IsActive]) 
FROM tblFloor_Master 
WHERE  FloorID = @FloorID;
```